# I can't send and receive data using API in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to send and receive data using Nodejs API but I'm stuck in this error

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
    WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER(../../third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:231))
#0      _SecureFilterImpl._handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:99:46)
#1      _SecureFilterImpl.handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:143:25)
#2      _RawSecureSocket._secureHandshake (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:920:54)
#3      _RawSecureSocket._tryFilter (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:1049:19)
<asynchronous suspension>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using `https://` but haven't installed an SSL certificate. So try to use `http://` instead of `https://`.